# In CNN (Convolutional Neural Network), does the combination of previous layer's filters make next layer's filters?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks

I know that the first layer uses a low-level filter to see the edge information. As the layer gets deeper, it will represent high-level (abstract) information. Is it because the combinations of filters used in the previous layer are used as filters in the next layer? ("Does the combination of the previous layer's filters make the next layer's filters?)
If so, are the combinations determined in advance?